# Is it possible to automatically disable the Excel Worksheet_Change event whilst processing the same event?

Tags: excel, events, vba

I have the following code that is connected to the InputSheet's `Worksheet_Change` event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  ' First, make sure we're working with an InputRange cell
  ' ALL OTHER CELLS: Exit, no action
  Dim rngCells As Range
  Set rngCells = Intersect(Target, InputSheet.Range("InputRange"))
  If rngCells Is Nothing Then
       Exit Sub
  End If

  ' Do interesting stuff that updates InputSheet
End Sub
```

This code is only designed to handle a subset of cells (InputRange), but updates other cells outside of this range. Each of these updates (and there can be a few hundred) will fire the `Worksheet_Change` event.

**Is there any way of disabling this during execution, and then re-enabling at the end?**

Eg. some languages have function calls to do this, or even in VBA a timer event can be disabled by pausing the timer.

I could add a simple flag, and this would avoid the `Intersect` call. No doubt this would give a good speed improvement, but it would still result in the unnecessary event callbacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

Then when you are done with the procedure:

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: That was a quick reply - looks like it works, thanks!  (Except I think you have EnableEvents true/false back to front - I'll fix it)